# TSQL XML character escape

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlxml

I try to convert this into XML:

```
DECLARE @xml XML;
SELECT @xml = (SELECT 'xxx' + nchar(0x10) FOR XML PATH('') );
```

I got error:
XML parsing: line 1, character 9, illegal xml character

But this works fine:

```
SELECT 'xxx' + nchar(0x10) FOR XML PATH('')
```

Is there a workaround for this?

On MS Connect nothing useful:
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/547817/xml-type-does-not-accept-all-character-escape-sequences

Comment: What xml output are you expecting to get? Note that the stand-alone example, while the query includes a `FOR XML`, *isn't* producing xml output...

Comment: I want to save this output to table with data type xml.
output is correct "<root><item>xxx&#x10;</item></root>" but can't be saved into db.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use any characters which are not comprised of the current sql server collation to assign to xml variable.